# Colour settings for Visual Studio 2015 tooltips containing code snippets

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using the “Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor” extension to change some of the colour settings. I’ve got most of it set up how I like it (Dark text editor with light UI), but I’m having trouble getting the tooltips shown in the text editor to be readable.

I’m not entirely sure what these tooltips are actually called. There’s a screenshot below showing what I’m referring to.

[image: Tooltip with unreadable text]

In this tooltip you get contextual help depending on what you’re hovering over with your mouse. In this case I’m hovering over the `history` attribute in the JSX snippet.

As you can see (or rather not see), the text between the parentheses and the sample code below the first line is the same colour as the background of the tooltip, which makes it impossible to read.

I cannot seem to find a setting that controls the colours for the (currently) invisible text. There are so many options, and none of the ones I’ve found seem to apply to text in the tooltips. Here are the tooltip settings that I’ve already changed:

[image]

Any idea what other settings I need to change to make the text readable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after several hours of trial and error. The setting to change is:

`Editor Tooltip -> Plain Text -> Foreground`

I changed it to a light grey, and now my tooltips are readable again.

[image]

Comment: I found some other parts of Visual Studio where the tooltip colours weren't usable, notably the tooltips for HTML elements and JSON config files. The following tool came in very hand for figuring out which settings to change in Visual Studio Color Theme Editor: http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/